# How to delete the highest paid employee from employee table?

Tags: mysql

**Employee** table consists of Employee_id, Employee name, and salary

How to delete the highest-paid employee from the employee table?
I tried

```
delete from employee
where salary = (select max(salary) from employee);
```

but it gives an error;

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'employee' for update
>   in FROM clause    0.0022 sec

Comment: This (if it did what you requested) would delete multiple employees if they shared the same high salary. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
delete from employee 
order by salary desc
limit 1
```

Or fixing your query

```
delete from employee 
where salary in 
(
  select * from (select max(salary) from employee) x
)
```

since you need to build a temp table as workaround because you select and delete from the same table.

Comment: the second command is showing                                                                                        ERROR: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.

Answer (score 0):

Bury it a bit deeper

```
delete from employee 
where salary = (select maxsalary from (select max(salary) maxsalary from employee) s );
```

This will delete ALL employees with maxsalary

Comment: why do we need to bury it deeper?

Answer (score -1):

This should do.

`delete from employee where salary = (select max(salary) from employee);`

Comment: This errors ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'employees' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data.